# MySQL - select rows where value = X, or if no matches, where value = null

Tags: mysql

How can I find all rows in a table where `val_b` has a specific value, but if no such row exists, I would like to see if there are rows that match with less specificity, thus where val_b is `null`.

From the table below, I would like to select where `val_a = X` and `val_b = T` and get the row with `ID:1` back.

If I select where `val_a = X` and `val_b = V` and get row with `ID:3` and `ID:4` back. Since row `1` and `2` didn't match, I will settle with the rows that have less specificity but still matches `val_a`.

```
| ID | val_a | val_b |
| -- | ----- | ----- |
| 1  | X     | T     |
| 2  | X     | U     |
| 3  | X     | null  |
| 4  | X     | null  |
| 5  | Y     | null  |
```

Is this possible to do directly in the DB query? Something like a syntactically left-associative `XOR` operator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ID, val_a, val_b
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    val_a = 'X' AND (val_b = 'V' OR
                     (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable
                              WHERE val_a = 'X' AND val_b = 'V') AND val_b IS NULL));
```

[image]

### Demo

The logic here is that we retain a record if one of the following conditions be true:

- `val_b` matches the intended (non NULL) value, or
- `val_b` is NULL *and* there are no matching non NULL `val_b` records

The `EXISTS` clause covers the second case, and it asserts there are no matching non NULL `val_b` records.

When searching for `val_a = 'X'` and `val_b = 'T'` only the `ID:1` record was returned using the above query.

If you are using MySQL 8+ then we can use analytic functions here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, val_a, val_b,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN val_a = 'X' AND val_b = 'V' THEN 1 END)
            OVER () cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, val_a, val_b
FROM cte
WHERE val_a = 'X' AND (val_b = 'V' OR (val_b IS NULL AND cnt = 0));
```

### Demo

But note that we still need to use a subquery, even in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I assume this makes two complete table scans. It would be nice if you could have MySQL to only do one, and if you don't get any hits in that query, it makes the second. (Not that my DB won't handle two scans, I'm very grateful for your reply!)

Comment: @AndreasLundgren I would expect that the MySQL optimizer would be smart enough to cache the `EXISTS` subquery, and only compute it once.  Then, MySQL would only need to make a single pass over the table.  Keep in mind that the `EXISTS` clause is not correlated to the outer query.

Comment: I also expect it to cache the EXISTS subquery, else we would have an ordo n^2 query, and that is not the case. But you still have two scans, one for the subquery and one for the outer query. If it would first scan to find for example all with val_b='V' and if no hit, scan again for null that would have made it statistically much faster. Not sure if an IF statement can be used, I didn't manage to get something that "compiled" with that. :-)

Comment: @AndreasLundgren I gave you an option using MySQL 8.  I'm not sure we can write this query without using more than one table scan.